# XSD.exe from DLL to XSD

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, dll, xsd.exe

I have been trying to convert a DLL to XSD using XSD.exe.

I am using the command

```
xsd.exe $(BinDir)$(TargetName).dll /outputdir:$(ItemDir) /type:$(ItemFileName)
```

and I am always receiving the message

> Warning: cannot generate schemas because no suitable types were found.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: xsd.exe does not "convert" dlls. It creates a description of their types. You are requesting `/type:$(ItemFileName)`, do you have a type in the dll named that way?

Comment: Remove the /type and see if you get output.

Comment: Yes i do.I have also tried to convert a single class with the cmd xsd.exe -t:ItemFileName ItemFileName.dll but i still got that message

Comment: i have just removed the  /type and i am receiving a reflection error. 
A default accessor must be implemented on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, as it inherits from ICollection.